# Difference Between '+' and '*' operation pattern in REGEXP

Tags: java, mysql, regex, database, operators

I have a table CANDIDATE in my db which is running under MySQL 5.5 and I am trying to get rows from table where xy is contains in firstname, so I can run below two queries

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM candidate WHERE FIRSTNAME REGEXP '^xy.+';
SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM candidate WHERE FIRSTNAME REGEXP '^xy.*';
```

I am Getting the same Result so want to get differences in these two REGEXP.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE. ab+ will match ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s; it will not match just ‘a’.
`*` causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’, ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.

Answer (score 4):

`*` **Zero** or more of the preceding element.

`+` **One** or more of the preceding element.

Answer (score 3):

`+` means one or more, `*` means zero or more

Comment: Means Counting of element. can you explain better ??

Comment: it tells something about the element right before, in your example the match-any-character operator `.`

Answer (score 1):

a* corresponds to repetition of "a" zero or more number of times

a+ corresponds to repetition of "a" one or more number of times

Answer (score 1):

> so want to get differences in these two REGEXP.

Add the name 'xy' to your database.